# Postgres Different Timestamps Within Functions

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, datetime, timestamp

I would like to utilize different timestamps within a Postgres function. Due to the fact that Postgres functions are executed in a transaction, I am unsure how to achieve this. If I use NOW() or CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() at different points within a function, they will all return the exact same result. Please see example below.

I have seen this accomplished before, so I am fairly certain it is possible. But I don't recall how the code was written.

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE "temp".foo (col timestamp(3));

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "temp".foo_ins()
RETURNS int
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
    
    INSERT INTO "temp".foo (col) VALUES (now());

    PERFORM pg_sleep(3);

    INSERT INTO "temp".foo (col) VALUES (now());

    RETURN 0;

END $function$;

SELECT "temp".foo_ins();

SELECT *
FROM "temp".foo;
```

Results:

```
2022-08-04 09:16:27.561
2022-08-04 09:16:27.561
```